# When using Semantic UI, I need to refresh the page before tabs activate

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI 2.0 at this URL: http://scctsi-tp-staging.herokuapp.com

However when navigating between sections using the main menu (like Clinical Trials, Organic Messages, Paid Messages etc.), the tabs on the section that you land on stop working. You need to navigate to the new section and hit Refresh before the tabs start working. (Note that the Collected Data section is not yet implemented.)

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like turbolinks prevents $(document).ready from firing. So none of the necessary initialization code was getting called!